# Loop through df column, comparing to list and creating new column

Tags: r, regex, loops

I have a column of numbers, like social security numbers for example. I would like to compare this column to a list of unacceptable values ( like `11111111` or `12345678` for example). There also some grepl operations i would like to perform, like the first 3 digits can't be `000`. Below is a skeleton of what I think the code could look like, I prefer a for loop logic.

```
ssns <- c(12343210,23454321,34565432,11111111)
badssns <- c(11111111,22222222)

for( i in 1:length(ssns)) {
    if(ssns[i] %in% badssn_list) {
        ssns$newcolumn==BADSSN
      }
    else if( grepl(first 3 numbers 0){
        ssns$newcolumn==BADSSN
      }
    else{ssns$newcolumn==GOODSSN}
}
```

Comment: You can use `%in%` for the first comparison. For the second one, you can use `grepl("^0{3}",ssns)` but `ssns` must be characters to start with. Then you can or these.

Comment: I think your first comparison should be `if(ssns[i] %in% badssns)`

Comment: Do i need to initialize the new column that is taking the BADSSN value?

Comment: You could, but you could also just use `ifelse(cond, BADSSN,GOODSSN)` where `cond` is the two conditions (or'ed) as I mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just using a nested `ifelse` should do the job imo:

```
ssns$newcolumn <- ifelse(ssns$num %in% badssns, 'BADSSN', 
                         ifelse(substr(ssns$num,1,3)=='000', 'BADSSN', 'GOODSSN'))
```

or shorter using an OR statement (`|`):

```
ssns$newcolumn <- ifelse(ssns$num %in% badssns| substr(ssns$num,1,3)=='000', 'BADSSN', 'GOODSSN')
```

which gives:

```
> ssns
       num newcolumn
1 12343210   GOODSSN
2 23454321   GOODSSN
3 34565432   GOODSSN
4 11111111    BADSSN
5 00065432    BADSSN
```

---

Used data:

```
ssns <- data.frame(num = c('12343210','23454321','34565432','11111111','00065432'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
badssns <- c('11111111','22222222')
```

Comment: so is the iterating logic for all of the comparisons in your answer in the %in%?

Comment: @Rob the `%in%` compares every element of `ssns$num` with the values in `badssns`

Comment: so the iterating logic for the following grepl statements is coming through the %in% as well?

Comment: @Rob What do you mean? There are no `grepl` statements in my answer ....

Comment: grepl is useless as he's already using substr to get the first 3 characters of the string.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have some experience with computer programming, but maybe are new to R.  In most cases, the best R programs don't use `for` loops.

Here's a more `R`ish way to accomplish what you've described.  It will be much faster when `ssns` and `badssns` are long.

```
ssns<-c(12343210,23454321,34565432,11111111)
badssns<-c(11111111,22222222)

good.idxs <- is.na(match(ssns, badssns))
good.ssns <- ssns[good.idxs]
```

You might want to work with strings rather than numbers -- maybe you are concerned the letter "oh" was used in place of the number "zero".  This approach works in that case as well.  Somewhat unexpectedly (for me, anyway), it even works when `ssns` is a vector of characters and `badssns` is  a vector of number or vice versa!

Answer (score 0):

If `ssns` and `badssns` are character vectors:

```
ssns<-c("12343210","23454321","34565432","11111111","00023456")
badssns<-c("11111111","22222222")
```

then you can use just one `ifelse`:

```
result <- ifelse(ssns %in% badssns | grepl("^0{3}",ssns), "BADSSNS", "GOODSSNS")
##[1] "GOODSSNS" "GOODSSNS" "GOODSSNS" "BADSSNS"  "BADSSNS"
```